# Does "kaze" also mean "a cold" in Japanese?

Tags: translation

I know the word "kaze" means "wind", but recently I was watching a Dragon Ball Super episode and the character 18 after sneezing says something that sounds like "kaze ka" when talking to herself. Does "kaze" also mean "a cold" or something like that in Japanese? When I look to translate "cold" to Japanese it translates it as "コールド" which sounds like an adaptation of that English word but it doesn't translate to "kaze". Also, does it have another meaning besides these possible 2?

Comment: An online dictionary with romaji (like jisho.org) might be a good place to start. http://jisho.org/search/kaze

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[風]{かぜ} is wind, however when talking about a cold, while it still is pronounced as かぜ, it is written as 風邪. When talking about catching a cold, you would say [風邪]{かぜ}を[引]{ひ}く.

> 「あ～風邪ひいてしまった～」

Comment: @Pablo, note that _kaze_ in this context means "**a** cold", not "**being** cold".  That second kind of "cold" is さむい for the weather or a room (as in the temperature), and つめたい for something you can touch with your fingers (like an ice cube) or for someone's behavior towards another person (like when something awful happens and someone else just says, "so what?").

Answer (score 1):

In traditional Eastern medical theory, it is believed that you catch a cold because of *Wind*.(please note that it is a symbolized expression)